# The probability that one bernoulli process has a higher p than another?

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I have two data generating processes that are independent Bernoulli processes with probabilities of success $p_A$ and $p_B$. I am taking repeated samples from these two data generating processes, so the distribution of each set of observations is an independent binomial.

I know the value of $p_A$ and $p_B$ but I do not know which process I am observing. I denote each observed process $\gamma \in \{1,2\}$ If I draw $n_1$ and $n_2$ from each of these processes, how do I define the probability that the observations from $\gamma_1$ are from data generating process $A$ (and by extension the other process $\gamma_2$ is from data generating process $B$) or the other way around?

Put another way, if a person were to know which process was $p_A$ and which was $p_B$ for sure and stated that process $\gamma=1$ was $A$, what is the probability that he is lying given the number of draws from each observed process? I think this question has a relatively simple description under a likelihood function, but my math keeps breaking down.

Also, is this a well defined problem if I don't know $p_A$ and $p_B$ and I have to estimate them? I'm not sure that it is.

Comment: Answering your first question (finding the probability that the first sequence of observations are from $A$) requires a *prior probability* distribution for $(A,B)$. That might be the missing piece that causes your math to "break down." It also helps answer your final question.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand this comment in the context of the first part. Do you mean a prior probability of $p_A$ and $p_B$ or a prior probability that the observed process 1 is the data generating process $A$?

Comment: @whuber, maybe I'm missing something but assuming $p_A, p_B$ are known parameters wouldn't it suffice to look at the likelihood ratio, $\dfrac{P(\gamma_1 | p_A)P(\gamma_2 | p_B)}{P(\gamma_2 | p_A)P(\gamma_1 | p_B)}\;$ ? Agree for the second part though, you would definitely need some sort of prior if $p_A,p_B$ are unknown also.

Comment: @alto the likelihood ratio doesn't tell you the *probabilities* P(A|data) or P(B|data).

Comment: @Glen_b good point. I was simply thinking in terms of deciding between $\gamma_1 = A,\; \gamma_2 = B$, and $\gamma_2 = A,\; \gamma_1 = B$. Obviously I implicitly assumed both alternatives were equally likely a priori, which is probably what whuber was getting at with need for a prior in the first place.

Comment: @alto I'm quite sure that's what he's getting at - when I saw the question I came to post what turned out was already his first sentence (almost word for word). We have no basis on which to tell the OP what priors should be used (we can always use such a prior as an example if we make it clear how to do it differently)

Comment: @alto I think I see the point being made now and I think didn't properly specify the setup. In this particular case, I think the implication is that both alternatives are equally likely since both processes are known to be observed, and I'm simply discerning which is which. If I have no a-priori reason to believe $\gamma_1=A$, the prior should effectively be diffuse. However, this is just the base case. The lying part of the problem is part of a strategic game that probably needs to satisfy PBE, which means I'll need to think more about the prior.